# Create multiple apps at the same time and caching the reference to db

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to make a use of Firebase cloud messaging I have nearly 1000 service account that means I got 1K app with me.

The service account can be initialised once

```
 var foo = admin.initializeApp({
                    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
                })
```

to send the notification

```
foo.messaging().sendToDevice(fcm_token, message)
                               .then((response) => {
                                    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
                                })
```

So I thought of caching the `foo` (saving a `foo` reference list) for all the 1K service account by initialising the app in the running memory. This works perfect

But in terms of scalability that's not the right way. so I thought of putting this in redis but data type of `foo` is `FirebaseApp`

could you please help in figuring out the way where I can catch the `foo` reference later use it.

**Fcm official example**

```
    // Initialize the default app
admin.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);

// Initialize another app with a different config
var otherApp = admin.initializeApp(otherAppConfig, 'other');

console.log(admin.app().name);  // '[DEFAULT]'
console.log(otherApp.name);     // 'other'

// Use the shorthand notation to retrieve the default app's services
var defaultAuth = admin.auth();
var defaultDatabase = admin.database();

// Use the otherApp variable to retrieve the other app's services
var otherAuth = otherApp.auth();
var otherDatabase = otherApp.database();
```